# jquery dialog box never pops up at all

Tags: jquery, dialog, click

so here is the code (I have tried many variations of this (with the div, without the div) and jquery itself is working, but not the dialog box) I can do an alert box, but if I put a dialog in, it never works. No popup, nothing. A basic dialog box does not work.

```
$('#link).click(function(){
  $('#dialog).dialog();
  }

 <div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title" style="display:none"> Some text</div>
```

Comment: Using a simple code colorer (like the one here on SO) makes the problem clearly visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So I figured out that in order to use the dialog box I had to include the jquery-ui declaration at the top of the page instead of just the jquery declaration.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js" ></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed a quote after the `#dialog` selector **and** the `#link` selector, try this:

```
$('#link').click(function(){
    $('#dialog').dialog();
}
```